# How to use #options folder:recursive properly in ServiceStack Bundler?

Tags: servicestack

I'm using servicestack bundler, but I have problem with "#options folder:recursive" - it doesn't load any files at all. There is a message in the Output window in VS, where I run bundler using

```
"$(ProjectDir)bundler\node.exe" "$(ProjectDir)bundler\bundler.js" "$(ProjectDir)Content\css"
```

post-build event, that says:

```
processing [my_path]\Web\Content\css/main.css.bundle:
option: folder -> recursive
```

but it doesn't create any result files, when I write path explicite everything works.
Does .bundle file should be put in special location, I have something like:

```
\Content
  \Content\css
  \Content\css\css1.css
  .
  .
  .
  \Content\main.css.bundle
```

Comment: also what do you mean by writing path explicitly? is it about a .bundle file content or about a path specified in a post-build step command?

Answer (score 1):

I assume a .bundle with `#options folder:recursive` should be at the root of your assets folder (**Content**, for instance).

I have just tried the similar setup for now it, but with [External tool](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Bundler#create-an-external-tool-inside-vsnet) enabled. It succeed.

According to the docs on Github, the `folder:recursive` turns on `nobundle` option by default to achieve *idempotent behavior* of bundling operation - so neither **\Content\main.css** nor **\Content\main.min.css** would be generated in case you wouldn't add such support manually.

To pass these limitations I've added an additional step to **bundle.cmd** - that deleting *.min.css and *.css in the root folder before bundling and also added `#options outputbundleonly` 'cause I usually don't need separate minified asset files.

Another limitation is that for some reason **ServiceStack Bundler** doesn't support **BundleOptions.Normal** with `#options folder:recursive` enabled, so maybe it's also your case. BTW, I have [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308558/servicestack-bundler-and-folderrecursive-behavior) about that with no answers yet.